# Agora Live video streaming - service minutes calculation

Tags: agora.io, billing

I am thinking to use https://Agora.io for my next project. But I am confused with the number of service minutes, which can make the cost reach to the sky.

In the case of only 1 broadcaster started live streaming for 30 mins with 100 viewers only watching and listening like a webinar.

How the service minutes will be calculated?

Will it be -

`1 Broadcaster * 30mins * 100 viewers = 3000 mins`

OR

`1 Broadcaster * 30mins = 30 mins` (as those viewers are not sharing the video or audio).

Answer (score 0):

The Agora pricing page is here: https://docs.agora.io/en/interactive-live-streaming/reference/pricing?platform=flutter

A broadcaster (Host) is charged at US$3.99 per 1,000 minutes for the lowest video resolution (and not including any no screen or video sharing by the host), so your host cost will be 12c for 30 mins. The viewers (audience) will cost US$1.99 per 1,000 minutes so that will be $6. Note that Agora allow a viewer to be promoted to a host during an event so it's not a passive live stream, hence the expense over other streaming services.